# Lumia 930 old notifications not removed

Tags: 8.1, notifications

The Lumia 930 (windows 8.1) has a strange behavior (or lack of normal behavior) which I think is un-intuitive and I would not be surprised if it is categorized as bug.
Story is short and simple

1. Phone is resting on table, idle, screen turned off
2. I hear a Whatsapp message notification
3. I open Whatsapp using live tile and read the message
4. I notice that the notification bar (top of screen) still has the message icon so something should be new
5. I open notification pulldown and it is for the message that I just read.

**Question** Shouldn't the notification disappear once I've read the message? Same happens with SMS messages and Emails. One has to click the notification itself (or use "clear all") in order to make it disappear. Shouldn't the OS be aware no new message/email is left and remove the notifications automatically? Any way around it? Am I missing something?

**Update**
Now that I've tested with more care, this issue can't be observed in case of SMS and Email notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the WhatsApp app. You can leave feedback for them in a review via the app's store listing.

Comment: You're right actually. Upon close inspection, I couldn't observe this issue in case of SMS and Email notifications